# Sort lines by length and alphabetical

Tags: sorting, text, notepad++, text-editor

Anyone knows how to sort lines this way in Notepad++ or other text editor?

So basically i want to turn this:

```
Dog
Cat
Horse
Elephant
Pig
Sheep
Mouse
```

Into

```
Cat
Dog
Pig
Horse
Mouse
Sheep
Elephant
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **SynWrite** you can make plugin. Call "Tools - New plugin", enter "mysort". Enter text and save

```
from sw import *

class Command:
    def run(self):
        text = ed.get_text_all()
        end = ed.get_prop(PROP_EOL)
        text = text.split(end)
        text = sorted(text, key = lambda x: '%5s'%len(x)+x)
        text = end.join(text)
        ed.set_text_all(text)
```

Then call via "Tools-Plugins".